# Understanding the virtualxid transaction type in postgres

Tags: performance, postgresql, transactions

I am trying to understand locks in postgres and here is what I have understood till now.

- pg_locks contains lock information
- All statements in postgres runs inside of a transaction either explicit/implicit. (Postgres 9.0 high performance)

As per my understanding virtualxids are not real transactions and transactionidxid is what indicates a transaction.

When I do a simple connect to the psql shell, and I query the pg_locks table there is already a virtualxid present there.

I have not initiated a transaction or ran a query, so why this virtualxid is created ? Is it because that this connection might initiate a transaction in the future?

What am I missing here?

Comment: I am relatively to new postgres, but I do know it uses MVCC, which only locks for writes, not reads.  Therefore, a select statement, which will run with an implicit transaction like you said, but should not acquire any locks.

Comment: That's right, but why create a virtualxid in the first place if it does not acquire any locks, a mere client connection creates a virtualxid.

Comment: The transaction would exist the moment the statement is run, regardless of what locks the statement ends up needing.  As for why simply connecting would create a transaction, I am not sure.  I can't answer that.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Connecting does not create a transaction but issuing `select * from pg_locks` implicitly does if the session hasn't a current open transaction already.
This is per the rule that you quoted in the question: *All statements in postgres runs inside of a transaction either explicit/implicit*

The query `select * from pg_locks` cannot be a neutral observer, as it requires for its own use a transaction and a lock on `pg_locks`. As a consequence, this select will always report **at least**  two entries as in the example below:

```
test=> \x
test=> SELECT relation::regclass AS relname, * FROM pg_locks;

-[ RECORD 1 ]------+----------------
relname            | pg_locks
locktype           | relation
database           | 113270
relation           | 11000
page               | 
tuple              | 
virtualxid         | 
transactionid      | 
classid            | 
objid              | 
objsubid           | 
virtualtransaction | 2/5789
pid                | 31376
mode               | AccessShareLock
granted            | t
-[ RECORD 2 ]------+----------------
relname            | 
locktype           | virtualxid
database           | 
relation           | 
page               | 
tuple              | 
virtualxid         | 2/5789
transactionid      | 
classid            | 
objid              | 
objsubid           | 
virtualtransaction | 2/5789
pid                | 31376
mode               | ExclusiveLock
granted            | t
```

Comment: I forgot that I was actually running a query for pg_locks.Now its clear, but why does postgres create it in the first place, any particular behind this design decision?

Comment: @GreedyCoder: `AccessShareLock` are acquired for objects involved in a query to block them from being modified or dropped by another session during their use.

Answer (score 7):

As long as you query pg_locks, you in fact run a query and hence start a transaction. It needs to acquire AccessShareLock on pg_locks, for instance. That's why virtualxid is allocated.

But virtual transaction id is quite "free" unlike real transaction id. Virtualxid is local to the backend (it consists of the backend number plus some sequential number). And real transaction id is system-wide 32-bit number, so there is a chance of wraparound when the counter wraps around to zero. [Special action](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/routine-vacuuming.html) must be taken to prevent the system from failure at that moment, so PostgreSQL is reluctant to allocate real transaction ids before they are actually needed.